# Lowest and highest price (grouped product) (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am looking to display the lowest and highest price on my grouped products only. 
Example can be seen here http://screencast.com/t/Xtndelwsk8h

I have tried a couple pieces of code in my grouped.phtml but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use tier pricing as follows :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

This will show on your product pages as follows :

```
buy 2 for $2 each and save 6%
buy 3 for $1.5 each and save 9% etc
```

Then you need to edit phtml file responsible for above calculation and change it as per your requirement in the screenshot.

I think the file used is catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml. enable profiler from settings>configuration>Developers for exact phtml file used.

hope this helps

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? I have a lot of products and I am just looking to display the lowest and highest price of the product.

Comment: where will you enter the lowest and highest price ?

Comment: in the grouped.phtml file

Comment: i mean to ask where in admin, obviously every product will have different prices..

Comment: I am using grouped products. Not configurable.